# WPF setup installation

Tags: c#

When i am trying to update my already installed msi setup, It is not correctly updated. It still has the old setup only. And i have done all the following steps,

- Set Remove Previous Installation as True
- Set Detect new version as True
- Your C# program's version must increase with every deployment
- You should change version of your installer to one higher version and it will ask you to change product code, select YES.
- Do not change your upgrade code, let it be same.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I have fix this issue. We need to change the assembly version also.